# How do i use micrometer with jmx in spring boot app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jmx, micrometer

I am fairly new to micrometer metric and having some issues with basic setup in my spring boot application.

Code:

```
MeterRegistry registry = new SimpleMeterRegistry();
Timer timer = registry.timer("app.event", "type","ping");
timer.record(System.currentTimeMillis() - date.getTime(),TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

I tried looking for a bean with the name of ping in jmx using jconsole, but I am not able to find it. I believe there is something basic I am missing here, but not sure of the real cause. I tried following the micrometer documentation as well, but it seems to explain different functions of micrometer without much sample examples. I would really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you haven't included the jmx exporter?

From the [documentation](https://micrometer.io/docs/registry/jmx):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
  <artifactId>micrometer-registry-jmx</artifactId>
  <version>${micrometer.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the auto-configured `MeterRegistry`. So you should inject `MeterRegistry` into any component you want to create meter(s) rather than creating your own one there. Or you can create your own one as a bean if necessary.

I created [a sample demonstrating how to do it](https://github.com/izeye/sample-micrometer-spring-boot/tree/so-51940816). Note that it's on the `so-51940816` branch, not the `master`.